# How to pass mmap to execve function in C?

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory, mmap

I am coding in Linux and trying to do some task by executing another program.

The master must execute slaves to make some word search on some input files (1 file per slave).
After all searching done, master will write the matchings lines found by the slave processes to an output file. I am trying to make the communication between master and slaves using named shared memory.

I need to pass my `mmap` call's pointer in the master's main to the other program and get it in there but I can not, because its type is not matching.

If I use semaphores for syncronization, I will also need to pass the shared semaphore's mmap. There is a code snippet below from the caller's `main` to execute slaves. I can reach newArgv by using argv in the slaves' main:

```
int f = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

unsigned int *addr = mmap(0, 10000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, f, 0);

char * newArgv[10];
for (int a = 0; a < numberOfFiles; a++) {
    newArgv[0] = wordToSearch;
    newArgv[1] = argv[3 + a];
    char * path = "./psearch2aslave";
    execve(path, newArgv, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Don't pass the pointer… it won't be the same pointer anyways. If you get a proper OS book and read its IPC chapter, it should say anonymous mmap won't support IPC between any processes. You probably want to mmap to an actual file, the pass the file name around.

Comment: If I pass the name, there is no point of using mmap. This not anonymous mmap, it is **named shared memory**.

Comment: I don't see you are passing name. You are passing null, hence anonymous.

Comment: If I pass 0 instead of NULL, is there a way to reach the mmap's address in another program with the use of 0 we're passing? Thank you for the warning, I should not have copied my old program's code directly without checking.

Comment: Please explain what kind of software you are developping and what your both processes are doing. So **edit the question** to improve it.

Comment: i am not sure what's your question. null is practically defined to be `(void *)0`. you need to pass a real file name so that IPC can be established between any two processes. again, anonymous mmap won't work arbitrarily. my ignorance prevents me from coming up functional cases other than the direct consequence of `clone` call.

Comment: Did you consider some multi-threaded approach? Why did you reject it?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. This is a just part of my Operating Systems course's project. And there was a thread version of this question which I completed right away :) That is why I am insisting on this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass `mmap` to an [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ed executable.

When `execve` is successful,  the entire [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is scraped and reinitialized for the executed ELF binary. That is one of the main roles of [execve(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). At startup, a program should expect a well defined memory state.

Maybe you might adopt a *convention*, like using some named file, and pass the name of that file as some program argument. Or passing a file descriptor, etc.

<sup>(IIRC, someone proposed many years ago a kernel patch to add a flag to [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) for memory mappings persistent accross `execve`; that patch was rejected, with good reasons; I completely forgot the details and could be very wrong)</sup>

Perhaps you want [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html). Or just adopt a convention with some file name and use `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED`.

Be aware that even if you share (virtual) memory, you need some means of synchronization. Read [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html), ....

Read also [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (both freely downloadable). See also [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (there are several ways to do [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)).

Comment: One could also pass a file descriptor past exec.